# Como criar um formulário de consulta com Angular?

Tags: angularjs, formulário, controller

Pessoa, como crio um formulário com alguns campos para consulta por exemplo:
Nome e Telefone e um botão Consultar para enviar esses dados para o backend consultar e exibir em uma outra View o retorno em uma tabela dinâmica.

Consigo fazer isso utilizando Service normalmente, mas só funciona uma única vez, quando tento realizar a mesma consulta os dados são retornados para a minha View, porém na minha tabela aparecem os dados do backend mas também aparece "Nenhum registro foi encontrado".

No meu sistema eu tenho o form com os campos vinculados ao Controller DadosCtrl e quando eu clico em consultar o meu Service chama outra rota com outro Controller ListDadosCtrl.

Como disse, os dados são trazidos normalmente mas só funciona na primeira vez.

Não sei se utilizar um controller para envio e outro para listar é a melhor forma.

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como posso criar esse formulário para consultas?

Segue o código que estou tentando fazer. Modifiquei algumas coisas para simplificar.

```
// View com Form de Consulta
<form name="frmClientesConsulta">
    <div class="row cells4">
        <div class="cell">
            <label>Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-control text" ng-model="dadclientes.nome">
        </div>
        <div class="cell colspan2">
            <label>Telefone:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-control text" ng-model="dadclientes.telefone">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <button ng-click="buttonExecute('consultar')">Consultar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ao clicar no botão ele executa a função abaixo para enviar ao service os dados que vou enviar para o backend consultar

```
//Controller DadosCtrl
define(['app'], function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.controller('DadosCtrl', ['$scope','$location','dadosCliente', function ($scope,$location,dadosCliente) {

        $scope.dadclientes = [];

        $scope.buttonExecute = function (nameAction) {
              if (nameAction == 'consultar') {
                dadosCliente.setItem($scope.dadclientes);
              } else if (nameAction == 'limpar') {
                $scope.dadclientes = [];
              };
        };


    }]);
});
```

o Botão chama o service abaixo para setar os valores num vetor para ser passado para o outro controller (ListDadosCtrl)

```
// Service dadosClientes
define(['app'], function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.service('dadosClientes', function dadosClientes($location) {
        var dados = [];
        return {
            getItem: function () {
                return dados;
            },
            setItem: function(value) {
                dados = value;
                $location.path('/dados/list_clientes'); // Essa Rota irá apontar para a VIEW que possui a tabela dinamica e o Controller (ListDadosCtrl)
            }
        };

    });

});
```

Ao chamar o controller abaixo, chamo novamente o service para dar um getItem e buscar os dados que
foram submetidos no form.

```
//Controller ListDadosCtrl
define(['app'], function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.controller('ListDadosCtrl', ['$scope','$location','dadosClientes', function ($scope,$location,dadosClientes) {

        var dados = [];
        $scope.clientes = [];
        dados = dadosCliente.getItem();

        if (dados.telefone == "123") {

          $http.get('http://localhost:3000/clientes').success(function(data) {

              if (data.length > 0) {
                $scope.clientes = data;
              }

          });

        }

    }]);
});
```

Nesse controller acima, estou só fazendo um SIMULAÇÃO, caso eu passe o valor de telefone 123
ele faz um GET e executa a busca de dados de alguns clientes.

No momento em que fiz o setItem no Service, já usei o $location para acionar a outra view onde os dados serão exibidos.

```
// View com Tabela Dinâmica que recebe os dados do BackEnd
<table class="dataTable"
       data-role="datatable"
       data-searching="true"
       data-paging="true"
       data-language="{{language}}">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NOME</th>
            <th>TELEFONE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cliente in clientes">
            <td>{{cliente.id}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente.telefone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Como comentei no post original, a busca dos dados sempre ocorre normalmente, o get funciona blzinha, mas infelizmente só ocorre uma vez.
Se eu volto no form de consulta e clico no botão novamente, os dados são exibidos na tabela porém por se tratar de um DataTable, a tabela não entende que possui registros e coloca a mensagem "Nenhum registro foi encontrado"

Talvez haja uma outra forma bem mais simples de construir o que estou precisando. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Sem ver o seu código fica difícil ajudar, post ele também

Comment: Emir, obrigado por avaliar... já coloquei o código, espero que dê para entender. Vlw

Comment: Chegou a debugar pra ver se no teu service já não retorna?

Comment: Entao, o service está funcionando sempre... e retorna os dados todas as vezes. A questao é que na minha view onde está a tabela... somente na primeira consulta é que fica populada corretamente... qdo volto no form e mando consultar os mesmos dados... a tabela é populada mas fica com a informacao de nenhum registro encontrado. Entao estou vendo se é possivel fazer isso de outra maneira pra eu tentar continuar usando minha datatable normalmente.

Comment: Essa info de nenhum registro encontrado é um tratamento que tu faz?

Comment: Entendi + ou - o que tu quer fazer. Uma tela para filtrar informações é isso? Vc tem várias formas de fazer isso. Confirme que posto uma sugestão que ficaria mais simples

Comment: Opa... a informacao de nenhum registro na verdade é um tratamento de uma api que peguei da internet http://datatables.net e mesmo quando eu populo o meu vetor de clientes para usar com ng-repeat na table acaba aparecendo que nao tem nenhum registro, mas enfim, a idéia é isso que vc falou mesmo. Uma tela para filtrar registros... porém a questao é que o resultado deve ser mostrado em uma view diferente da view onde está o form com os filtros. Se vc tiver um exemplo te agradeço demais. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Já ouviu falar no filter do angular? Não te ajudaria?

Comment: Já ouvi sim.. mas sinceramente não consegui pensar em alguma forma de utilizá-lo com o objetivo de montar o form que estou precisando. Vc tem alguma idéia diferente?

Comment: Poderia informar de forma mais detalha o pq da necessidade de duas views?

Comment: Bom... estou migrando o sistema um pouco antigo que era em php e nele tinhamos esse comportamento. Em uma página eu tenho o form e ao mandar consultar os dados do form, ele direcionava para outra página com os resultados exibidis numa table, mas se vc tiver uma sugestao melhor talvez seja interessante utilizar. Como te disse, nao sei se estou indo pelo melhor caminho tentando essa abordagem.

Comment: Tenho uma sugestão sim, porém vou conseguir monta-lá só no final do dia. Pode ser?

Comment: Opa... que isso cara... vc já está me ajudando demais. É claro que pode!!! se quiser mandar pro meu email, pode mandar tb. and.gmartins@gmail.com. Obrigado

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui e vê se ajuda. Nesse exemplo faço um sroll-infinito com angular e java: https://github.com/emirdeliz/meus-projetos/tree/master/scroll-infinito-angular-rest-datafactory/src/main/webapp/assets/js

Comment: Caso contrário a noite faço algo mais próximo do teu exemplo

Comment: Emir, vi o seu exemplo e ele é bem bacana mas ainda acredito que a forma não é essa. Avaliei novamente meu código e vi uma falha no momento de popular o meu $scope.clientes. Não lembrei de colocar no post mas uso algumas telas genéricas através de ng-template, então para cada tela diferente eu tenho uma propriedade no meu controller onde informo qual a view que será carregada. Ex.: $scope.viewname = 'list-clientes' mas só que eu estava atribuindo o valor antes de fazer o GET no backend. agora coloquei após a atribuição do $scope.clientes = data e parece que funcionou.

Comment: Caso ainda queira me mandar algum outro modelo para que eu possa avaliar... fico mto grato e agradeço novamente por toda sua atenção. Vlw demais mesmo.

Comment: Blz, a noite dou uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

Veja se o exemplo abaixo lhe atende. Ao meu ver é mais amigável além de usar alguns dos melhores recursos disponíveis com angular (ordenação e filtro de tabela).

```js
var clienteApp = angular.module("ClienteApp", []);
clienteApp.factory("$servicoGenerico", function($http, $q) {
  function ajax(url, parametros, metodo) {
    var requisicao = $http({
      method: metodo,
      url: url,
      data: parametros
    });

    var promessa = requisicao.then(function(resposta) {
        return (resposta.data);
      },
      function(resposta) {
        return ($q.reject("Something went wrong"));
      }
    );
    return promessa;
  }
  return ({
    ajax: ajax
  });
});

clienteApp.factory("$cliente", function($servicoGenerico) {
  return {
    consultarPorNomeTelefone: function(nome, telefone) {
      var promessa = $servicoGenerico.ajax("<url consulta back-end>/" + nome + "/" + telefone, "", "<metodo consulta(POST, GET, ETC...)>");
      return promessa;
    }
  };
});

clienteApp.controller("ClienteController", function($scope, $cliente) {
  $scope.ordenacao = "nome";
  $scope.ordenacaoReversa = "false";

  $scope.consultar = function() {
    /* Aqui simularia a consulta no back-end */
    //$scope.cliente = $cliente.consultarPorNomeTelefone($scope.nome, $scope.telefone);

    /* Colocando um mock para simular comportamento */
    $scope.cliente = [{
      nome: "SSA Comunicações",
      telefone: "(47)8899-6788",
      cidade: "Rio do Sul"
    }, {
      nome: "Argoville",
      telefone: "(47)3465-5435",
      cidade: "Joinville"
    }, {
      nome: "Brahma",
      telefone: "(51)4367-9877",
      cidade: "Joinville"
    }, {
      nome: "Antartica",
      telefone: "(67)8977-6655",
      cidade: "Blumenau"
    }, {
      nome: "Stackoverflow",
      telefone: "(77)8644-3334",
      cidade: "Jaraguá do Sul"
    }];
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container" ng-app="ClienteApp" ng-controller="ClienteController">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nome">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sucess btn-sm" ng-click="consultar();">Buscar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Telefone:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="telefone">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sucess btn-sm" ng-click="consultar();">Buscar</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <p>Sort Type: {{ ordenacao }}</p>
    <p>Sort Reverse: {{ ordenacaoReversa }}</p>
    <p>Search Query: {{ filtro }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filtrar" ng-model="filtro">
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="ordenacao = 'nome'; ordenacaoReversa = !ordenacaoReversa">
                        Nome
                        <span ng-show="ordenacao == 'nome' && !ordenacaoReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="ordenacao == 'nome' && ordenacaoReversa" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="ordenacao = 'telefone'; ordenacaoReversa = !ordenacaoReversa">
                        Telefone
                        <span ng-show="ordenacao == 'telefone' && !ordenacaoReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="ordenacao == 'telefone' && ordenacaoReversa" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="ordenacao = 'cidade'; ordenacaoReversa = !ordenacaoReversa">
                        Cidade
                        <span ng-show="ordenacao == 'cidade' && !ordenacaoReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="ordenacao == 'cidade' && ordenacaoReversa" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in cliente | orderBy:ordenacao:ordenacaoReversa | filter:filtro">
        <td>{{ item.nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.telefone }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.cidade }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```